# Regarding Tomcat logs and issues

Tags: java, multithreading, apache, tomcat

while working with Tomcat I see, few log files like

```
commons-daemon.2015-11-16
tomcat7-stderr.2015-11-16
tomcat7-stdout.2015-11-16
```

Why do we have these files created? is there some issue with my configuration.
I am asking this as I am facing issue like my tomcat stops responding and a restart is needed once in a week.

While debugging, I came across these files and noticed that, one of the file
which is named like 'commons-daemon.2015-11-09' has below content, does it mean 
    the thread started at 9th and when I stopped it on 16th again writes it to same file.

```
[2015-11-09 12:47:07] [info]  [ 3264] Commons Daemon procrun (1.0.15.0 64-bit) started
[2015-11-09 12:47:07] [info]  [ 3264] Running 'Tomcat7' Service...
[2015-11-09 12:47:07] [info]  [ 3056] Starting service...
[2015-11-09 12:47:09] [info]  [ 3056] Service started in 2106 ms.
[2015-11-16 10:19:18] [info]  [ 3804] Stopping service...
[2015-11-16 10:24:19] [info]  [ 3804] Service stop thread completed.
[2015-11-16 10:25:19] [info]  [ 3264] Run service finished.
[2015-11-16 10:25:20] [info]  [ 3264] Commons Daemon procrun finished

1. is it normal to have these files?
```

Comment: well yes there are few bugs in other log files, some times there is out of memory and while shutting tomcat it says " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load [org.apac
he.cxf.message.FaultMode]. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the threa
d which caused the illegal access.
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1335)" I am looking into that also but concernd abt these log files.

Comment: Paste log file content here.. what are you getting in log files?

Comment: 11-Nov-2015 17:12:27.263 WARNING [http-nio-8443-exec-9] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [SomeABCServices] appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:526)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)